# setting SL4A in PyDev(Eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, sl4a

I'm working with sl4a.I chose to work with my laptop remotely.I followed the instructions below and everything is working fine.

```
1.copy 'android.py' into site-packages of python
2.start private server in sl4a
3.adb forward tcp:9999 tcp:58755
4.export AP_PORT=9999
5.work with python from terminal
```

Now I want to work on pydev in eclipse instead of mac osx terminal.How do I set the above configurations in eclipse(pydev)?

Answer (score 0):

The same basic approach applies to Eclipse with PyDev:

1. Open a new workspace.
2. Configure the interpreter for Python, but go to the "Environment" tab and set AP_PORT=9999 (or whatever port number you are using).

You can also do this per-run configuration if needed.

Then you can code like you normally do, although content-assist will not be functional for most of the SL4A API.

Also remember when creating projects to work in, you should set your Python grammar version to 2.6 (as that's currently the highest supported by SL4A).